# Делаю рассылку выдает: TypeError: send_messages() got multiple values for argument 'bot' Как исправить?

Tags: python, postgresql, aiogram, asyncpg

```
async def send_messages(bot: Bot):
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(user=settings.db.db_user,
                                 password=settings.db.dp_password,
                                 database=settings.db.db_database,
                                 host=settings.db.db_host)

    rows = await conn.fetch('SELECT user_id FROM users')
    for row in rows:
        user_id = row['user_id']
        await bot.send_message(user_id, "Второй раунд")

    await conn.close()
```

Comment: Проверьте что находится в переменной `user_id`, там может находится массив содержащий в себе требуемый вами параметр под 0 индексом, если это так, вместо `user_id` в вызове функции `send_message` используйте `user_id[0]`